# Azure Stream Analytics Job has no input or output

Tags: azure

I am using Blob Storage as an Input (JSON file). I have tested the Query, the Query seems fine. I have specified Output as an Azure SQL Server Table. I can connect to this database from SSMS and query the table.

The Job status is running but I don't see any data loaded into the SQL table. I have checked Azure Management Services the status is Running there are no errors. How do I diagnose what is going on?

Note: I have left Blob storage path prefix as empty. I would like it to grab any file that comes into the storage container and not some specific files.

Comment: pathPattern "path prefix" is not required, so it's being blank should not have an affect. Can you post the query?

Comment: Removed previous comment, ASA *does* allow processing of events stored in BLOBs. It is not an ETL tool though. There may be a problem with your file format. Have you tested your query with a representative sample? If you upload a succesful test file to your container does your query work? Try adding a second output to another BLOB container and a second query `SELECT * INTO OUTPUT2 ...` to ensure that the problem isn't with the *input*. If no data appears, there's a problem with the input. If it does, the problem is in the query

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a query? You first need to create a query and then start your stream analytics.

Query Example:

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    Output
FROM
    Input
```

Comment: I have created and tested the query. It works fine. I have now realised that if I stop the Stream Analytics job, then upload Files into the Blob storage, then Start the Stream Analytics job again it does not stream/load those files. However, if I upload the files while Stream Analytics job is running it successfully load it into the Azure SQL Table. Do you know how to change this behaviour, so that when the new files are uploaded to Blob storage when the stream analytics job is not running, when it runs the next time it loads the new files?

Comment: The purpose of Stream Analytics is to process a stream of data. If you want to process it when it's already in the right place you could consider a Scheduled WebJob!? Would be good to know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @wuerzelchen ASA *does* support BLOBs as event inputs, not just reference data. This is *not* something weird if eg the data comes from an API gateway, batch or scheduled processing.

Comment: Yes Panagiotis, that's correct. I was just reffering to the issue that there needs to be a trigger to trigger stream analytics. I'm not sure of the possibility to solve the problem greypanda has, is with ASA.

Comment: @greypanda maybe you could use Azure Data Factory for your solution as well? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-copy-data-wizard-tutorial/
Would be really helpful if you could point out your problem what you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an output to PowerBI and run the SA. This will show you if the data schema and the query is right. If everything goes well, you should be able to see the JSON files as a dataset with the name values listed. You can create a mini dashboard for just the count of items received so you can in real time see if its loading and processing the JSONs from the BLOB.

If it fails, under operation logs to PBi output, it will tell you the data schema isn't supported.

Hope this helps!
Mert